# how to remove sorting from listView in specific column in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

How do I remove sorting from listView (eg Account) in specific column in SugarCRM?

Specific : I want to Remove sorting on Name field (only one field) of ListView of Account Module.

Answer (score 5):

Set 'sortable' => false for the field in the listviewdefs.php. Edit custom/modules/Accounts/metadata/listviewdefs.php and set such as:

```
'EMAIL1' => 
array (
'width' => '16%',
'label' => 'LBL_LIST_EMAIL_ADDRESS',
'sortable' => false,
'customCode' => '{$EMAIL1_LINK}{$EMAIL1}</a>',
'default' => true,
),
```